# How to add a simple calendar to my windows store app

Tags: visual-studio-2013, calendar, windows-store-apps

I'm working on a Universal windows store app and I want to add a simple calendar so that users can add birthdays of their friends and save them and some other stuff. Is there any simple way to do this?

PS: Using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do understand about Calendars, is there are fourteen of them in total that are possible - seven for each day of the week a normal year begins on, and seven more for leap years. You may have to create all fourteen and put them in somehow. There is instead a formula for working out what day of the year anyone was born on by their date of birth, and formulae can be programmed into r or other programmes using perhaps the for loop, or if command. This formula is :

{4(d+y)+x-4c}/28, where d is what number day of the year it is - so Jan 1st, d=1, and so on, but for Leap Years it gets different from Feb 29, y is the year in question, x the closest year before y divisible by four, and c an era constant. For modern dates, c=0, so no worries, but if You go back before September, 1752, it changes, as this is when the British went from the Julian to the Gregorian, while in Catholic Europe it was October, 1582, but these are only a concern if You are into such historical dates. For those, c=1, but may have different values much earlier - if You want to know more, reply to this, and I will get out what I have written on it.
For example, if one was born on 17th May, 1979, you would go :

{4(137+1979)+1976-4 times zero}/28, which equals 372 plus six sevenths - you ignore the whole number, and look at how many sevenths there are. Six means Thursday, and thus the 17th May, 1979 was a Thursday. This is it in short - for more details, if this interests, feel free.

Comment: Very interesting!! Although I was looking for a more simple way because I need to make this app fast, I will probably try this when I'm little less busy with other projects and I will update my app like so. If you have anything more to add plz do!! :D And I'll get back to you when I have time to implement this!

Comment: Yes, I will consult what I have written on this Subject, and see what I can add.

Comment: With respect to Perpetual Calendars, I was an amateur Historian long before becoming a Mathematician, but having some knowledge of Maths, I used it to solve a problem I had long seen in other versions of Perpetuals, in that they only covered the  years from 1800 to 2000, or up to 2100, ignoring the 1700's, since they did not want to deal with the awkwardness of of the change over in 1752, and the loss of the eleven days, which at the time caused civil unrest in the UK - although not much has changed in that respect. More to come - need to partition this to not go over character limit.

Comment: Now, being interested in especially British Medieval History, I wanted to know what Day of the Week any event in History occurred in, and not many books, even if they tell us the exact date, will also give the Day, so in 1991 - 1992, I worked on this problem until I came up with a Calendar that solved it. In 2000 I then perfected my own Perpetual Calendar, using an arrangement that listed all the years from 1 AD to 3180, arranged in seven columns, based on the day of the week they began on, then set up two day distribution charts, one for normal, the other for leap years.

Comment: which had every date, also arranged in seven columns, but no days assigned to them, so one would look for a year, say, 1346, a non leap year, which began on a Sunday, then look at the day distribution chart for non leap years, assign Sunday to the first of January, and therefore every date in that same first column would also be a Sunday, so if one wanted to know the day that May 11th, 1346 fell on, one would start at the very left column, all Sundays, at least for this particular year.

Comment: then follow it down to May, seeing that the 7th, 14th, 21st and 28th of May were also Sundays, then follow along from the 7th to the right to the  11th, to find it in the column that would belong to Thursdays - as long as one keeps track of the fact that for 1346, the first column in the day distribution table applies to Sundays - all the Sundays of that year - and that therefore the next column are Mondays, and so on. I then copyrighted this work and verified it in January, 2001 at a Lawyer's Office, where he still has a copy of it.

Comment: This was fine, and I intend to print these off in booklet form to sell soon, but then in 2004 I got hooked on Mathematics, and in doing so, studied all sorts of things - I have at home 17 school exercise books full of my own and others' ideas,  and then I saw somewhere someone came up with a formula similar to the one I showed - so no, this formula is not entirely mine, but the form it is in now is, as I adapted it for Perpetual use.

Comment: Because the Calendar changed from Julian to Gregorian, as it was causing the Seasons to go out of whack, they not only skipped over some days, they reassigned different days of the week to dates that would other wise have had a different one, so this is what caused the problem. But if You use my adapted formula, with zero as the error constant c for any date from Tuesday  1st January , 1901, up to now and beyond until the end of 2100, a Friday,  then it will work.

Comment: For the dates from Thursday, 14 September 1752,  until Wednesday the 31st of December, 1800, you use 5, and for Thursday Jan 1st, 1801 – Monday, Dec 31st, 1900, one uses 6, and  for dates up to Wednesday, 2 September 1752, in the United Kingdom and its Territories, you use 1.

Comment: But for Catholic controlled Europe the change was earlier,  with Julian Thursday, 4 October 1582, being followed by Gregorian Friday, 15 October 1582, so up to the first date c = 1, the dates 5th-14th October, 1582, do not exist in Spain, Portugal and much of Italy, among others, with France going over to Gregory on Sunday, 9 December 1582, being followed by Monday, 20 December 1582, then for most of them, from the 15th October, 1582, until Friday Dec 31, 1700, the constant is 4, while from Saturday, Jan 1, 1701 until Wednesday Dec 31, 1800, it is 5.

Comment: It is best to check these dates out on something like Wikipedia™, and remember in the formula, once the relevant value of c has been found, it must be multiplied by four. I also have pages on dates and maths in my On the Hub Pages, if You would like to have a look.

Comment: sure where can I find the hub pages?

Comment: Try http://hubpages.com/feed/ , then look up things by subject, or check out my own ones - my user name is cbl12.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is in use third-party controls like [Telerik Calendar](http://www.telerik.com/windows-universal-ui/calendar) or something free [like this one](https://winstoreappcalendar.codeplex.com/).